# Imagick not using custom fonts when converting SVG to JPG with PHP

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I'm having an issue with custom fonts not rendering when attempting to convert an SVG to a JPG image.  I am using `font-family="Lobster"` defined for an SVG text element.

My server setup is as follows:

- CentOS 6.5 (32 bit)
- ImageMagick 6.5.4-7
- PHP 5.2.17

The PHP code I am testing with, but does not work.  I am attempting to use the custom font **Lobster**.

```
//Setup SVG to be read by Imagick.
$SVG = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$SVG .= '<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">';
$SVG .= '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="158px" height="92px" viewBox="0 0 158 92" enable-background="new 0 0 158 92" xml:space="preserve">';
$SVG .= '<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 32 58)" font-family="Lobster" font-style="normal" font-size="20px" font-weight="400">Lobster</text>';
$SVG .= '</svg>';

$image = new Imagick();

//Convert SVG to JPG
$image->readImageBlob($SVG);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");

//Save the thumbnail.
$save_path = '/home/username/lobster.jpg';
$image->writeImage($save_path);


echo '<img src="lobster.jpg" alt="" /><br />';
```

Which produces the following image:

[image: Lobster.jpg]

## What I have tried:

I've created a **type.xml** file located at `/home/username/.magick/type.xml` with the Lobster font definition as shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE typemap [
<!ELEMENT typemap (type)+>
<!ELEMENT type (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT include (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST type name CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST type fullname CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type family CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type foundry CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type weight CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type style CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type stretch CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type format CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type metrics CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST type glyphs CDATA #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST type version CDATA #IMPLIED>
<!ATTLIST include file CDATA #REQUIRED>
]>
<typemap>

  <type
     format="ttf"
     name="Lobster"
     fullname="Lobster"
     family="Lobster"
     glyphs="/home/username/fonts/Lobster/Lobster.ttf"
     style="normal"
     stretch="normal"
     weight="400"
     />

</typemap>
```

I've included a direct include in the `/usr/lib/ImageMagick-6.5.4/config/type.xml` file like this:

```
<typemap>
   <include file="type-ghostscript.xml" />
   <include file="/home/username/.magick/type.xml" />
</typemap>
```

When outputting the fonts using the `$image->queryfonts();` method, I can see the **Lobster** font defined in the list.  For example, this:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$fonts = $image->queryfonts();
foreach($fonts as $font) {
    echo $font . '<br />';
}
```

Returns this:

```
[...]
Hershey-Plain-Triplex-Regular
Hershey-Script-Complex-Regular
Hershey-Script-Simplex-Regular
Lobster
MeriendaOne
NewCenturySchlbk-Bold
NewCenturySchlbk-BoldItalic
NewCenturySchlbk-Italic
NewCenturySchlbk-Roman
[...etc]
```

Additionally, I believe ImageMagick is using it's own internal SVG renderer.   The shell command:

```
convert -list format | grep SVG
```

Returns:

```
MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.26.0)
SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.26.0)
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't working?

Comment: It works from the command line (i.e. saving the SVG as a file and then calling `convert test.svg test.png`) and I can't see any errors. It's possible it's a bug in ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem converting SVG to PNG using Imagemagick but was unable to make it work using that approach. I was somehow able to get the result I need using docraptor:

```
 DocRaptor.createAndDownloadDoc("YOUR_API_KEY", {
    test: true, // test documents are free, but watermarked
    type: "pdf",
    document_content: document.getElementById('container_of_svg').innerHTML
  })
```

Just make sure to add the font declarations inside the container_of_svg element like below and make sure to add an absolute URL to your fonts:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DaimlerCS-Demi';
    src: url("https://staging.xxx.com/xx/fonts/xx/FontCS-Demi.eot")
}
page {
      size: 21.16cm 15.87cm;
      padding: 1cm;
      margin:0;
      background: #E6E6E6;
}
```

Just check their document here: https://docraptor.com/documentation/jquery

Note: docraptor is not free but if your client can pay for it, I think its a solid option.

Answer (score 0):

Please restart your webserver, or PHP-FPM instances.

Apparently the information about which fonts can be used in an SVG is cached by ImageMagick, even though the list returned by queryFonts() *isn't* cached.

Your code example didn't work for me until I restarted my php-fpm instance, and then it worked perfectly.

Comment: This didn't work.  I even had the host upgrade the PHP version to 5.4, install Inkscape and still no dice.  I believe it's an issue with the current version of ImageMagick I'm using.  I'm hoping they can upgrade it.  I'll report back if that solves the issue.